# Batch file - would like to display a menu of folders in 3 columns

Tags: batch-file, directory, menu

1-column code is below.  I'd like to expand "char" to 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and then be able to display the options in 3 columns (21 items, 21 items, 20 items).  Folder names over a certain length would have to be truncated.  With 3 columns and potentially long folder names, long folder names would have to be truncated in the menu.

```
rem Set the number of lines per page, max 29
set "pageSize=29"
set "char=0123456789ACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

rem Load current directory contents
set "numNames=1"
for /D %%a in (*.) do (
   set /A numNames+=1
   set "name[!numNames!]=       %%a"
)

cd ..
set /A numPages=(numNames-1)/pageSize+1

rem Show directory contents, one page at a time
set start=2
:ShowPage
set /A page=start/pageSize+1, end=start+pageSize-1
if %end% gtr %numNames% set end=%numNames%
cls
cd %folder%
echo Page %page%/%numPages% of %CD%
echo/
set "base=1"
set /A lastOpt=pageSize+base, j=base
for /L %%i in (%start%,1,%end%) do (
   for %%j in (!j!) do echo     !char:~%%j,1! -  !name[%%i]!
   set /A j+=1
)

rem Assemble the get option message
set "mssg= (B - Back): "
if %end% lss %numNames% (
   if "%mssg%" equ " (B - Back): " (set "mssg= (") else set "mssg=%mssg%, "
   set "mssg=!mssg!Z=Next page"
)
if "%mssg%" neq " (B - Back): " set "mssg=%mssg%): "

:GetOption
choice /C 0123456789ACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZB /N /M "Choice%mssg%"
```

I've found batch file solutions to browse files/folders with GUI, but I don't want to do a call to GUI (Explorer) because I'd like to keep everything on the keyboard (slows progress down to switch back and forth between mouse and keyboard all the time).

Comment: Just to clarify...is your question how to display a selection menu for 63 directory name items in three columns. If so can you submit a [mcve] of just that part of your code, and explain to us where it is failing. We aren't here to code your task for you, we are here to help you to fix your failing attempt at that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem Set the number of lines per page, max 29
set /a pageSize=29
:: my pagewidth
SET /a pagewidth=120
SET "choicenames=z0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"


:: remove variables starting #
FOR /F "delims==" %%e In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,%pagewidth%) DO SET "#spaces=!#spaces! "

:: Read dirnames to #nn, count to #entries

FOR /d %%e IN ("%~1\*.") DO SET /a #entries+=1&SET "#!#entries!=%%e"
SET /a #entries+=1&SET "#!#entries!=z Quit."
SET /a #columns=(#entries + pagesize - 1) / pagesize
SET /a #rows=(#entries + #columns - 1)/#columns
SET /a #columnwidth=(pagewidth/#columns) - 3
SET "#choices=z"

FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,%#entries%) DO (
 rem column contents - max length + terminal spaces 
 IF %%e neq %#entries% (
  SET "#%%e=!#%%e:~-%#columnwidth%!%#spaces%"
  SET "#%%e=!choicenames:~%%e,1! !#%%e:~0,%#columnwidth%!"
  SET "#choices=!#choices!!choicenames:~%%e,1!"
 )
)

FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,%#rows%) DO (
 SET /a cols=%%e + %#rows% 
 SET /a #line=%%e + (%#rows% * 2^)
 SET "cols=!cols! !#line!"
 SET "#line=!#%%e!"
 FOR %%y IN (!cols!) DO IF DEFINED #%%y SET "#line=!#line! !#%%y!"
 ECHO !#line!
)

IF %#entries% gtr 36 (
 choice /cs /c %#choices%
) ELSE (
 choice /c %#choices%
)

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
 ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %ERRORLEVEL%
 SET /a #choices=%ERRORLEVEL%-1
 CALL SET "userchoice=%%#!#choices!%%"
 ECHO choice made : !userchoice:~2!
) ELSE ECHO QUIT!

GOTO :EOF
```

This should be a self-adjusting menu.

I chose to make the QUIT choice consistently `z`

Comment: @fortissimo : SO has a chat facility. I have created a chat room for discussions. Unfortunately, you need 20 reputation to use it. That's reasonably easy to obtain if you provide some sensible responses to questions or ask reasonable questions.